# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in Entity Framework work but i want the data in database not to be deleted while we change in model or add ur class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've just started using enity framework. I used Database Intializer. What I want to do is changing properties of database like adding table, field and ol.
Using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` it works but the data in database is deleted.So is there any way I can change database property without deleting previous data?

Comment: Do you mean update model from DB ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/04/01/update-model-from-db.aspx

Comment: yes wana update model without deleting previous data in database.

Comment: So, tutorial that I wrote its link helps you.

Comment: You may want to check these out aswell http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621 and this http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/

Comment: Updating database using migration sound more like manual coz we gotto use package manager console for it.is there any other way thats more like automated>

Comment: When you enable migrations, Configuration.cs file get's generated. You can set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; in the constructor so the database get's automatically updated every time you change model structure and run your application. I prefer to use Add-Migration command in the console just to make sure database get's updated correctly but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Entity Framework Code First Database Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621). Another place to see this at work is in [this video by Scott Guthrie](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2364).